# TestCases collections is not retrieved correctly through SDK but only with Web Service api

Tags: rally, testcase

SDK retrieval of TestCases collection from the TestSet object is not working correctly IMO as TestCase collection is not a full array of objects and TestCases collection has very scarce information.
Web service API returns them correctly and so far only 2.0p5 returns them correctly and neither of 2.0rc rc2 and rc3 returns them as expected

Am I doing something wrong?

I just need to get TestCases collection with all fully qualified objects for each test case when I retrieve a TestSet object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AppSDK rc2 works with v2.0 of WS API. v2.0 removed the ability to return child collections in the same response for performance reasons. Per [WS API documentation fetching a collection](https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/rest_collections.jsp) will return an object with the count and the url from which to get the collection data. To get full objects a separate request is needed. In [app example in this github repo](https://github.com/nmusaelian-rally/test-results-by-build-iteration/blob/master/App.js) when a testset is selected from a combobox, and testset loaded, TestCases collection is hydreated:

```
 _onDataLoaded: function(store, records){
        if ((records.length === 0) && (this._grid)) {
            this._grid.destroy();
        }

        var that = this;

        var promises = [];
         _.each(records, function(tcr) {
            promises.push(that._getTestCase(tcr, that));
        });

        Deft.Promise.all(promises).then({
            success: function(results) {
                that._testcaseresults = results;
                that._createGrid(records);
            }
        });
    },
         _getTestCase: function(tcr, scope) {
            var deferred = Ext.create('Deft.Deferred');
            var that = scope;
            var testcaseOid = tcr.get('TestCase').ObjectID;
            Rally.data.ModelFactory.getModel({
            type: 'Test Case',
            scope: this,
            success: function(model, operation) {
                fetch: ['FormattedID','Name','Method'],
                model.load(testcaseOid, {
                    scope: this,
                    success: function(record, operation) {
                        var testName = record.get('Name');
                        var testFid = record.get('FormattedID');
                        var testMethod =  record.get('Method');
                        var tcrRef = tcr.get('_ref');
                        var tcrOid  = tcr.get('ObjectID');
                        var tcrVerdict  = tcr.get('Verdict');
                        var tcrBuild = tcr.get('Build');

                        result = {
                            "_ref"          : tcrRef,
                            "ObjectID"      : tcrOid,
                            "Verdict"       : tcrVerdict,
                            "Build"         : tcrBuild,
                            "TestCaseName"      : testName,
                            "TestCase"   : testFid,
                            "Method"    : testMethod   
                        };

                        deferred.resolve(result);    
                    }
                });
                }
            });
            return deferred; 
        }
```